# Dragging the mouse outside of a clickable area

Tags: processing

I'm trying to code a slider from scratch and I've got a basic functionality, but I'd like to be able to drag the sliders beyond the bounds I created for clicking on it.

```
void slide()
{
  if ((x+w >= mouseX) && (mouseX >= x) && (y+h >= mouseY) && (mouseY >= y) &&
      (mousePressed == true))
  { 
      h = (mouseY - y);
  }
```

As you can see when the mouse is dragged outside of the slider dimensions, the height value no longer changes. How can I activate only within the dimensions then drag outside of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this trough a boolean to control the click and lock, like:

```
class Test {
  //global  
  float x;
  float y;
  float w, h;
  float initialY;
  boolean lock = false;

  //constructors

  //default
  Test () {
  }

  Test (float _x, float _y, float _w, float _h) {
    x=_x;
    y=_y;
    initialY = y;
    w=_w;
    h=_h;
  }


  void run() {

    float lowerY = height - h - initialY;
    float value = map(y, initialY, lowerY, 100, 255);
    color c = color(value);
    fill(c);
    rect(x, initialY, 4, lowerY);
    fill(200);
    rect(x, y, w, h);
    float my = constrain(mouseY, initialY, height - h - initialY );
    if (lock) y = my;
  }


  boolean isOver()
  {
    return (x+w >= mouseX) && (mouseX >= x) && (y+h >= mouseY) && (mouseY >= y);
  }
}


//end of class

Test[] instances =  new Test[3]; 

void setup() {
  size(200, 600);
  noStroke(); 
  instances[0] = new Test(20, 20, 40, 20);
  instances[1] = new Test(80, 20, 40, 20);
  instances[2] = new Test(140, 20, 40, 20);
}

void draw() {
  background(100);
  for (Test t:instances)
    t.run();
}


void mousePressed() {
  for (Test t:instances)
  {
    if (t.isOver())
      t.lock = true;
  }
}

void mouseReleased() {
  for (Test t:instances)
  {
      t.lock = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks like it will work fine,
do I need to define mousePressed() myself? It doesn't seem to work despite it being highlighted.
Thanks a lot

Comment: No, mousePressed() is a built in method. It should work... What is going wrong?

Comment: I was using it in my slider class within run which called under draw()
How/where do I use it exactly?
(I posted some test code as an edit to my question but it needs to be reviewed)
You've been a big help thanks.

Comment: Ah, now i saw your edit, it was already rejected by some one. But you should use mousePressed and mouseReleased out side any other block. Not inside your class. Also you still need to check for rect insideness, or it will work just as a mouseClicked ion any place. I'll will change the code again with yours class, hold on...

Comment: Glad it works. Just as a note: in code comments i said a global boolean was needed... Well not really, in fact maybe not desired... You could do the lock a member variable and set it, each instance un mousePresed, like `instance.lock = true;`. This might be important if you have more than one slider...

Comment: Yeah that's a good point, in my actual slider I avoided it by linking the "mousePressed ==" boolean to Lock(). That way it can all be part of "slider1.run()". Is there a reason its better to use the method version?

Comment: Hummm, I don't feel comfortable to affirm which is the better way. And I'm aways learning better ways of do the same task. Anyway I'm not sure if i understood your comment. I edited the code above again with a new version with 3 sliders. Also I mapped the value to use as a color indicator. Check it out :)